# Java user start program vs file start program

Tags: java, file-type

I'm making a program that will be run in Windows and to open a custom file type with it. I know how to associate the file type with the program, but is there a way to tell whether the program was opened by the user (blank screen when opened, no content visible) or whether the program was started by opening a file associated with the program (double click file and it start the program so the content in the file is visible)?

Comment: Yes there is a way: don't ignore the `String[]` that was passed to the `main` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your `static void main(String[] args)` method, the `args` is actually the command-line arguments to your program.

If there are no arguments, it was opened by itself, but if there *are* any arguments (specifically, you are interested in just the first), then it was **most likely** started by double-clicking on a file associated with your program, and that first argument will then be the full path to the file.

Comment: Ermmm ... What if I start the program by hand giving some argument?

Comment: @StephenC Thus the "most likely" (that I conveniently emphasized already).

Comment: I don't see any scientific basis for quantifying the likelihood as being "lost likely".  For example, if the application typically requires arguments, then a non-zero argument count is not even a useful hint.

Comment: @StephenC Right, but you wouldn't have an application with multiple other command-line arguments if you want it to be runnable by opening a file with an associated extension.